# How to write streaming DataFrame into multiple sinks in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a set of SQL rules which I need to apply on a streaming dataframe inside `foreachBatch()`. After applying those rules, the resultant/filtered dataframe should be written to multiple destinations like "delta" and "cosmos DB".

Below is what I have tried:
Using that static dataframe coming from `forEachBatch()` method, I am trying to create a temp view as below.

```
df.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(writeToDelta _)
  .outputMode("update")
  .start()

def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) {
    microBatchOutputDF.createOrReplaceTempView("testTable")
}
```

But while running the code, its showing as table or view 'testTable' not found.

Is it possible to create a temp table/view using static dataframe in spark structured streaming ?

Or how can I write to multiple sinks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments clarifying OPs question:

> "I have a set of SQL rules which I need to apply on the dataframe inside forEachBatch(). After applying the rules, the resultant/filtered dataframe will be written to multiple destinations like delta and cosmos DB."

The [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) allows you to

- Reuse existing batch data sources
- Write to multiple locations

In your case I understand you want to apply different transformations on your streaming dataframe and write it to multiple locations. You can do it like below:

```scala
df.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

  // persist dataframe in case you are reusing it multiple times
  batchDF.persist()

  // apply SQL logic using `selectExpr` or just the DataFrame API
  val deltaBatchDf = batchDF.selectExpr("") 
  val cosmosBatchDf = batchDF.selectExpr("") 

  // write to multiple sinks like you would do with batch DataFrames
  // add more locations if required
  deltaBatchDf.write.format("delta").options(...).save(...)
  cosmosBatchDf.write.format("cosmos").options(...).save(...)

  // free memory
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had today the same issue. I created a temp view with the dataframe received as a parameter, but even though no exceptions or warnings were thrown, when I tried to query that table in an sql statement, Spark couldn't find the table. I checked the SparkSession object outside and inside the function and it was the same instance. The problem - I think - is the visibility context of the table or something like that. What I did to fix it was to get the SparkSession from the dataframe received and use it to execute the sql statement. This way, Spark found the table perfectly fine.